# Bizarre PHP error: function not recognizing its own parameter

Tags: php

I have the following function:

```
  public function updateCustomerInternetBanking($value, $column_to_go_by)
  {
    $sql = "
      UPDATE customer c
        JOIN account_import ai ON c.account_import_id = ai.id
        JOIN generic_import gi ON ai.generic_import_id = gi.id
        JOIN import_bundle ib ON gi.import_bundle_id = ib.id
         SET has_internet_banking = 1
       WHERE c.".$column_to_go_by." = ".$this->quote($value)."
         AND ib.id = ".$this->quote($this->getId())."
    ";

    $conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection();
    $conn->execute($sql);
  }
```

When I try to run it in development, it works fine. When I try to run it in production, I get this:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: column_to_go_by in /var/www/mcif/lib/model/doctrine/ImportBundle.class.php on line 655
```

How could `$column_to_go_by` be undefined?!

And just so you know, this code is copied straight from production and I checked that the `WHERE`... line is line 655.

Comment: Well, where did you define this variable? :)) Upon calling this function

Comment: What kind of a value does `$column_to_go_by` get filled with?

Comment: Are the PHP versions and error handling configuration the same between development and production?

Comment: If it says it's undefined, then it is undefined. Then you have the old code on the production or you're looking in the wrong file.

Comment: @Wouter Jan van Tilburg: Sorry, I don't follow.

Comment: @Pekka: It's a string. It doesn't seem like it would be relevant *how* it's defined though, only *if* it's defined.

Comment: What happens if you don't pass it a variable, but a string? `$Whatever-> updateCustomerInternetBanking(22, "Hello");`

Comment: @mellamokb: Yeah, 5.3.3 on both. Why would error handling configuration matter? If PHP thinks `$column_to_go_by` is undefined, there's no value there, whether the notice gets reported or not. (It's a *notice*, not an error, by the way. I should have said that.)

Comment: @meze: You would think so, but when I grep for `$column_to_go_by` I just get those two lines from that function I pasted in my question.

Comment: @Jason: In my experience, notices tend to get hidden in development but shown in production.  Obviously, if you already know that it has a value in development, then that's irrelevant.  But sometimes different error reporting can cause a stray notice that wasn't expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are passing both variables correctly?

A method call like this:

updateCustomerInternetBanking(999);

would produce this kind of error.

Comment: This is exactly what was happening. I had an old version of a certain file that I had since renamed. When I rsynced into production, that file never got deleted, and since the class name stayed the same, the file was getting autoloaded. The old file called `updateCustomerBanking()` with the wrong number of arguments.

Comment: nice, thought that if you didn't pass an argument that has no default value, it'd give a fatal error. But it's just a warning in PHP.